# Is it somehow possible to style an iframes before/after pseudo-element?

Tags: css, iframe, styling, pseudo-element, css-content

As the title says, is there a way to style an iframes pseudo `before`/`after`? Without wrapping the iframe with another `div`, or else?`

I tried to style it like any other element, but no success:

```css
iframe::before {
    content: 'foo';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

iframe::after {
    content: 'bar';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ppRqm/

**Update**

A known workaround is to add the before/after to an element in the source file:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ppRqm/2/

But sometimes you've no access to the source-file.

Comment: The fiddle link is dead and I'm not seeing the workaround you mention on a [mirror of the link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170422153009/http://fiddle.jshell.net/ppRqm/2/)...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I am not sure but I think it isn't possible. Or the logic behind an iframe makes it imposible to achieve.

As you know, pseudo-elements are ***added* to its container**, if you do that with an iframe, pseudo-elements would be added inside the iframe.
But, and here's the problem, the iframe content, the *inline content*, will just load if the browser doesn't support iframes.

This means that this:

```
<iframe>
  <div>Your browser doesn't support iframes</div>
</iframe>
```

And adding pseudo-elements, will do the same thing; on modern browsers *inline content* **wouldn't be displayed**.

Answer (score 3):

**Direct Work-Around for Debugging Purposes**

I have a debugging CSS tier that gives an `outline` to elements with invalid or obsolete code. While not exactly an answer someone may find it helpful as I was trying to find a way to visually ensure that any content embedded with an iframe had an `allowfullscreen="true"` attribute/value. This work-around uses a sibling selector and it works well-enough.

```
iframe:not([allowfullscreen]) + *::after
{
 background-color: #f00;
 border: #f00 solid 4px;
 color: #fff;
 content: 'Missing allowfullscreen attribute on iframe!' !important;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding: 4px;
}
```

**Direct Styling using Third Element**

If you're looking to position relative to the iframe my next recommendation would be to set the iframe's parent position to `position: relative;` and *then* set `position: absolute;` on a *third* element to match the iframe's rendering. Lastly you could finally apply the `::after` on that third element.